# How to prove correctness of recursive algorithm

Tags: algorithm

```c
// sorts the items from L[i] through L[j]
void threewaysort(int[] L, int i, int j) {
    if (L[i] > L[j]) swap (i, j);
    if (j - i + 1 > 2) {
        t = (j - i + 1) / 3;
        threewaysort(L, i, j - t);
        threewaysort(L, i + t, j);
        threewaysort(L, i, j - t);
    }
}
```

The above code is sorting a list *L* from smallest to largest. To prove this algorithm is correct, I think we can use induction? The hint is, the call `threewaysort(L, 0, L.length-1)` actually has the side effect of making *L* sorted.

But I'm currently stuck in the steps of an induction proof.

Comment: This doesn't seem to truly sort the list, does it? Imagine `L = (2, 0, 1)` and we call `threewaysort(L, 0, 2)`. The function starts with `i = 0` and `j = 2`. It then proceeds to swap `i` and `j`. It  then simply terminates.

It looks like you are trying to implement merge sort, except you split the list in three chunks, not two. If that is the case, then you need to also merge the (now sorted) chunks when your return from the three recursive calls. Then the proof of correctness will be almost identical to the proof of merge sort.

Comment: @CătălinFrâncu, "it then simply terminates": no, it continues as j - i + 1 > 2.

Comment: In the example above, when `i` and `j` are swapped, we end up with `j = 0`, `i = 2` and the condition does not hold. Reading your answer, I guess the intention is to swap `L[i]` with `L[j]`.

Comment: Yes, @CătălinFrâncu, it would have been clearer if the OP had provided the implementation of `swap`, and would have called it passing L as a parameter also, like `swap(L, i, j)`, so it would work similarly as how arguments are passed to the main function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can indeed use induction. Let's use the notation *L<sub>i,j</sub>* to denote the subarray with the items from *L[i]* through *L[j]*.

### The base case

There are two base cases for this induction proof:

1. *j - i + 1 = 1*

   This means there is only one element in *L<sub>i,j</sub>*, and by consequence it is already sorted. Neither `if` condition is true, and so nothing happens: *L<sub>i,j</sub>* is sorted after calling `threewaysort(L, i, j)`.
2. *j - i + 1 = 2*

   There are two elements in *L<sub>i,j</sub>*. If not yet sorted, the first `if` condition is true, and the call to `swap` will effectively sort *L<sub>i,j</sub>*. The second `if` condition is false. So *L<sub>i,j</sub>* is sorted after calling `threewaysort(L, i, j)`

### The induction step

We arrive at the cases where *j - i + 1 > 2*

There are now at least 3 elements in *L<sub>i,j</sub>*. The proof by induction let's us assume that the `threewaysort` works correctly for smaller subarrays.

We ignore for the moment that a `swap` might be performed and focus on the body of the second `if` only, which *will* be executed:

*t* is guaranteed to be greater than zero.

Three recursive calls are made: on subarrays *L<sub>i,j-t</sub>, L<sub>i+t,j</sub>*, and again *L<sub>i,j-t</sub>*.

Let's define:

*A = L<sub>i,i+t-1</sub>*
      *B = L<sub>i+t,j-t</sub>*
      *C = L<sub>j-t+1,j</sub>*

These are non-overlapping, adjacent ranges of *L<sub>i,j</sub>*. The sizes of *A* and *C* are both *t*. *B* has size of **at least** *t* (could be *t*, *t*+1 or *t*+2).
Let's also define the plus notation to represent the union of two subarrays. So then *L<sub>i,j</sub>* = *A+B+C*, and the recursive calls actually sort *A+B*, *B+C* and then *A+B* again.

As *t* is strictly positive, *A+B* and *B+C* are smaller subarrays than *A+B+C*, and so we may assume these recursive calls successfully sort the corresponding subarrays (induction premise).

Let's see what happens with the *t* greatest values in *A+B+C*. Those that are not in *C* will end up in *B* after the first recursive call (recall that the size of *B* is at least *t*). So then we are sure the *t* greatest values are all in *B+C*. After the second recursive call we can thus be sure that all those *t* greatest values are only to be found in *C*.

A similar thing happens with the *t* smallest values in *A+B+C*. After the first recursive call none of them can be in *B* any longer, but that is not really helpful. After the second recursive call none of them can be in *C* anymore. After the third recursive call none of them can be in *B* either, and so they are all in *A*.

Summarising we get that:

- *A* is sorted (because after the last recursive call *A+B* was sorted)
- *B* is sorted (same reason)
- *C* is sorted (because after the second recursive call *B+C* was sorted, and *C* was not touched during the third call)
- *A* has the smallest values from *A+B+C*
- *C* has the greatest values from *A+B+C*
- *B* has the remaining values from *A+B+C*

This means that *A+B+C* is sorted.

This completes the proof by induction.

### Fewer swaps

The proof demonstrates also that the swap is optional for when the size of the array is different from 2. So the code would even be correct like this:

```
void threewaysort(int[] L, int i, int j) {
    if (j - i + 1 > 2) {
        t = (j - i + 1) / 3;
        threewaysort(L, i, j - t);
        threewaysort(L, i + t, j);
        threewaysort(L, i, j - t);
    } else if (L[i] > L[j]) {
        swap(L, i, j);
    }
}
```

However, performing the swaps as depicted in the original code will on average lead to fewer swaps (but more comparisons).

## Time Complexity

First we note that apart from the recursive calls all other statements execute in constant time.

Secondly, the recursive calls are made on an array that has a size that is approximately one third smaller.

So with *n = j - i + 1*, the recurrence relation is:

*f(n) = 3·f((2/3)n)*
      *f(2) = f(1) = 1*

If we expand the recurrence, we get:

*f(n) = 3<sup>2</sup>·f((2/3)<sup>2</sup>n) = ... = 3<sup>k</sup>·f((2/3)<sup>k</sup>n)*

When *k* is chosen such that *(2/3)<sup>k</sup>n = 2* (or 1) then we know that *f((2/3)<sup>k</sup>n) = 1*, and that factor can be omitted from the expression:

*f(n) = 3<sup>k</sup>*

Now we must resolve *k* in terms of *n*:

*(2/3)<sup>k</sup>n = 2*
      *k = log<sub>3/2</sub>(n/2)*
      *k = log<sub>3</sub>(n/2) / log<sub>3</sub>(3/2)*
      *k = 2.7 log<sub>3</sub>(n/2)*

So, now we have:

*f(n) = 3<sup>k</sup>*
      *f(n) = (3<sup>log<sub>3</sub>(n/2)</sup>)<sup>2.7</sup>*
      *f(n) = (n/2)*<sup>2.7</sup>

Which sets the time complexity approximately to:

*f(n) = O(n<sup>2.7</sup>)*

... a quite inefficient sorting algorithm; less efficient than Bubble Sort.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, I'm learning algorithm and recurrences recently and having trouble of understanding those concepts. But your response is clear and useful that helps me a lot with these materials.  But I have one more question, what is the running time of this algorithm, it would be better if you can tell the recurrence function for f(n). (assume j - i +1 = n)

Comment: See addition to my answer.

Comment: Did you check...?

Comment: Yes, I actually worked with my colleague before you edited it and we came up a same solution as yours. Thanks for your concerned.